# c# How make a typeconverter for a basic type like byte[]

Tags: c#, arrays, string, typeconverter

I have a lot of structures made in C++ COM server like

```
mystruct { char name1[16]; char name2[32]; }
```

When I send these structures to a C# COM client they become

```
mystruct { byte[] name1; byte[] name2; }
```

Now I want to show these structures in a property grid in C#.
How can I make a TypeConverter that converts byte[] to/from string.
The problem is not the `ConvertTo` and `ConvertFrom` procedures. They are fairly easy to make.
What I don't understand is how I get the property grid to use the TypeConverter.
I can get TypeConverter to work if I have a struct where there is a TypeConverter for the whole struct, but how to get the TypeConverter to work for a basic type like byte[]

Comment: why you didnt use `string` with `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=16/32)]` instead `byte[]` in your C# struct?

Comment: COM types are normally auto-generated from a type library.  That prevents adding the [TypeConverter] attributes you'd need to direct PropertyGrid.  So don't do it that way, write your own C# class that is easy to edit and copy the struct fields into that class before exposing it.